# How to use jquery to scroll down current screen?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am working on a project like agentur-loop.com. 
I want to know how does the current screen go down, not the whole page.

Comment: You mean how screen scrolls down when you click to menu item?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and then use it like this:

```
$(function () {

      $("li").click(function(){
       scrolView(this.id);

          });
   });
```

**FUNCTION:**

```
function scrolView(i) {
           $('div').each(function () {
               if (($(this).attr('id'))==i) {
                   $('html, body').animate({
                       scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
                   }, 1000);
               }
           });
       }
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/XeCu8/)